# meta X-UA-Compatible: difference between IE=Edge and IE=100

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

Some features of one of my web applications is not working properly for some users in internet explorer 9, though I have made it compatible for IE 9. After doing some investigation I found the problem will happen if IE9 opens the site with document mode IE7.

To get rid of the problem I instantly used the following meta tag to force the browser to use its latest engine all the time to open this site.

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge' />
```

I found another option to use this meta with content='IE=100'.

As most of my problems were css related, which option will have the minimum impact on other browser scripts?

Comment: I think whatever article you might have been reading was just illustrating a point, that with future versions you may be able to render in that mode by setting it to `IE=[version]`, whether it's version 10 or 100. However, if the idea is to just tell IE to use the latest rendering mode, `IE=Edge` should suffice.

I should hope by version 100 they will have gotten rid of this nonsense.

Comment: Probably the stuff you've read describes which mode is used when when a non-sense value is set to X-UA. `100` is a non-sense value in X-UA content attribute.

Answer (score 0):

See *Understanding legacy document modes* in [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Starting with IE11, edge mode is considered the preferred document
> mode. (In earlier versions, it was considered experimental.)
>
> [...]
>
> Starting with Internet Explorer 11, content values greater than "10"
> lead to edge mode, which is the highest version supported by the
> version of Internet Explorer used to view the webpage.